# Stacked histogram with datetime in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked histogram with datetime objects, but I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() < float()
```

The code does work when I either convert the objects to timestamps or when I use one range of data (no stacking).

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 21, 13, 45), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 23, 37, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 43, 18), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 16, 14, 12), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 11, 32, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 6, 29, 25), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 22, 54, 49), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 18, 41, 50), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 14, 25, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 3, 1, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 21, 10, 20), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 11, 29, 38), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 20, 34, 14), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 16, 58, 47), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 10, 54, 40), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 18, 17, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 15, 44, 58), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 17, 25, 9), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 12, 33, 7), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 26, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 12, 46, 13), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 3, 38, 24), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 21, 11, 59), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 13, 30, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 14, 6, 20)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 20, 59, 53), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 14, 3, 41), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 9, 37, 17)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 17, 18, 32)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 23, 15, 24)]]

fig, histograms = plt.subplots(5, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)
h = histograms[1][0]
h.hist(data, stacked=True)
```

This is the code without stacking:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 21, 13, 45), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 23, 37, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 43, 18), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 16, 14, 12), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 11, 32, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 6, 29, 25), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 22, 54, 49), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 18, 41, 50), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 14, 25, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 3, 1, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 21, 10, 20), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 11, 29, 38), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 20, 34, 14), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 16, 58, 47), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 10, 54, 40), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 18, 17, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 15, 44, 58), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 17, 25, 9), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 12, 33, 7), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 26, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 12, 46, 13), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 3, 38, 24), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 21, 11, 59), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 13, 30, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 14, 6, 20), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 20, 59, 53), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 14, 3, 41), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 9, 37, 17), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 17, 18, 32), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 23, 15, 24)]

fig, histograms = plt.subplots(5, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)
h = histograms[1][0]
h.hist(data, stacked=True)
```

NOTE:
As per answers, this is considered a bug. For future visitors I have filed a bug report https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5898 in case you want to track progress

Comment: I updated my answer with the example you asked for. Here I would go for bin width of 1 day, which makes N=6. In reality I have much more data

Comment: Yes, it does work in version 1.5.0. Yes, as in question I posted it also works  using timestamps (seconds since UNIX epoch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, revealed by version 1.5.x supporting histograms of single series of `datetime` type data.  Previous versions of matplotlib would not histogram datetime data whether stacked or not, failing with a similar error that said datetime could not be compared with float.

The Exception is thrown by [this line of code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.5.x/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5996).  As you can see, that is called only when bin edges are not specified and is trying to find the minimum in the time series (comparing it with `np.inf` and taking the minimum of those).  You can workaround this by specifying bin edges in the call, but then that leads to a further failure as the numpy histogram function called under the hood looks for less than zero width bins.

"Under the hood" when a single list of `datetime.datetime` objects is passed to the `pyplot.hist()` function, the data are actually converted to UNIX epoch timestamps (you can guess this from the labels of the x axis).  This is not done when the input is a list of lists of `datetime.datetime` objects.

At that stage, I think we have to call it a bug and you will have to use `timestamp` as you have already discovered - e.g. `h.hist([[t.timestamp() for t in s] for s in data], stacked=True)`.  You can still give the bin labels in date format, even though the actual data being histogrammed are timestamps, thus this should be transparent to the user.

I'll have a look to see whether I can find a nicer workaround / fix and possibly raise an issue on the matplotlib github.

Code that works (matplotlib 1.5.1, Python 3), albeit a bit messy

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 21, 13, 45), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 23, 37, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 43, 18), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 16, 14, 12), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 11, 32, 8), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 6, 29, 25), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 22, 54, 49), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 18, 41, 50), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 14, 25, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 3, 1, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 21, 10, 20), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 11, 29, 38), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 20, 34, 14), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 16, 58, 47), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 10, 54, 40), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 18, 17, 42), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 15, 44, 58), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 17, 25, 9), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 12, 33, 7), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 19, 26, 15), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 12, 46, 13), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 30, 3, 38, 24), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 21, 11, 59), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 25, 13, 30, 34), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 14, 6, 20)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 28, 20, 59, 53), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 27, 14, 3, 41), datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 9, 37, 17)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 17, 18, 32)], [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 23, 15, 24)]]

fig, histograms = plt.subplots(5, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)
h = histograms[1][0]

h.hist([[t.timestamp() for t in l] for l in data], stacked=True)

locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs,[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in locs], rotation='vertical')
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
fig.set_size_inches(4, 15)

plt.show()
```

Produces

[image: Stacked bar with date labels]